# Problemas com adapter em Fragment

Tags: java, android

Estou tendo problema com adapter no Fragment.

Meu Fragment:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Fragment {

    private final DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);    
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        ContactImageAdapter adapter;

        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts("Bancada");
        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            //add contacts data in arrayList
            imageArry.add(cn);
        }

        // linha com erro!
        adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.screen_list,imageArry);  

        ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); // linha com erro!
        dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Detalhe, em uma Activity não dá erro.

Comment: Qual erro que dá? Você tem duas linhas com erro?

Comment: Obrigado Lucas! The constructor ContactImageAdapter(HomeActivity, int, ArrayList<Contact>) is undefined e The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type HomeActivity

Comment: Emerson, mova esse codigo que da erro (e tudo associado) para depois do inflate no `onCreateView`. No lugar onde esta (onActivityCreated) a View ainda não foi construida, por isso os erros que encontrou.

Comment: Como assim obrigado? Obrigado pelo que? @Emerson Barcellos eu não fiz nada, rsrsrsrs. Poste o log de erro por favor.

Comment: wakim, fiz o que me pediu e continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: A página aqui está atualizando depois...merda...De qualquer modo poderia postar o construtor da classe ContactImageAdapter?

Comment: `public class ContactImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Contact> data=new ArrayList<Contact>();
public ContactImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Contact> data) {
super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
this.context = context;
this.data = data;
}`

Comment: @EmersonBarcellos postar o código dessa forma aqui no comentário está ilegivel. Por favor edite sua pergunta e coloque o código lá editado e bonitinho por favor.

Comment: Pelo visto o erro é de compilação e não de runtime. Poderia incluir a mensagem do compilador e do logcat caso tenha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embora tenha colocado o código da classe `adapter` como comentário acredito que consegui visualizar o erro. A classe `ContactImageAdapter` tem um `construtor` que espera um `context, int, ArrayList<Contact> data`. Você na hora que cria o seu adapter no fragment não está passando os `argumentos` corretos para os `parâmetros` do construtor da classe `adapter`.

***Mude esta linha:***

```
adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.screen_list,imageArry);  // linha com erro!
```

***Para esta linha:***

```
adapter = new ContactImageAdapter( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.screen_list, imageArry);  // linha sem erro!
```

***Mude esta linha:***

```
ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); // linha com erro!
```

***Para esta linha:***

```
ListView dataList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list); // linha sem erro!
```

---

Recomendo você deixar seu código desta maneira:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Fragment {
    private final DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());
    private ListView dataList; // Seu ListView.

    // Neste método você inicializa tudo referente a seu layout, como por exemplo os componentes gráficos que tem na tela, neste casso, em R.layout.main
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        dataList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list); // criação do List View antes estava lá no onActivityCreate e agora veio para cá.

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        ContactImageAdapter adapter;

        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts("Bancada");
        imageArry.addAll( contacts ); // Pode adicionar assim ao invés de percorrer no for aprimorado e adicionar um por um.

        adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.screen_list,imageArry);

        dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Se quiser pode ainda criar as variáveis como campos é claro e, não como variáveis locais.

Comment: Ok lucas muito obrigado, vou tentar aqui.

Comment: Ok! funcionou belezinha, tu é o cara lucas valeu!

Comment: Que nada @EmersonBarcellos. Quanto aos erros que você cometeu, O primeiro erro foi que o construtor do Adapter queria um objeto do tipo `Context` e você não estava passando. Você estava passando a referência `this` do Fragment e não o `context`. O segundo erro era que o método `findViewById` precisava ser invocada de uma `View` e no caso essa `View` teria que ser o seu layout e você não estava fazendo isso. Estava chamando o método diretamente da instância do Fragment. Compreendeu?